# First loop formatting on Magento onepage order review step 5 - first product listing data is out of alignment with columns

Tags: magento-1.6

Can anyone assist on how to edit this formatting, so that the first rendered product is not out of alignment with the table columns?

**Screenshot:** http://awesomescreenshot.com/099jf0d1f

**I located the source file as the below,** but seeing this is Magento it's not that simple.

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->getTotals()): ?>
<tfoot>
    <?php $_colspan = $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 5 : 3; ?>
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?>
    <?php if ($this->needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()):?>
    <tr>
        <td class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $_colspan; ?>">
            <small><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Your credit card will be charged for') ?></small>
        </td>
        <td class="a-right">
            <small><?php echo $this->displayBaseGrandtotal() ?></small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
</tfoot>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**I further isolated what appears to be the full formatting of this area in:**

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<tr>
<!-- ##################### -->
    <td><h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></h3></td>
        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($addtInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock()):?>
            <?php echo $addtInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </td>

 <!-- ##################### -->  

    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>

     <!-- ##################### -->     

    <td class="a-right">


        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>


           <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
         <!-- ##################### -->  

    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
    <td>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
    <td class="a-right">
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
    <td>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved from what I can tell..

I spent about 5 hours researching why the first line item of the Order Review section was showing problematic. The main files under question:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

In this file, about line 29 I removed I replaced this:

with this

You'll see I just cancelled out the id. This id might be tied to a decorateTable() method on the same page, but I cannot determine this for sure at this time.